# How do I configure VPN connections on Ubuntu Server with no GUI?

Tags: vpn

I can use either PPTP or L2TP. All the tutorials I find require a GUI to setup the connections. However, I want to connect from a virtual server to which I have only SSH access. Any hints?

Answer (score 5):

To use PPTP, you need to do the following:

First, install the `pptp-linux`, `pppd`, `ppp` packages. Then, create a file in `/etc/ppp/peers/`. The file name is irrelevant, but this name will be used to switch on the PPTP tunnel, so name it something meaningful. The file (the "peer file") should contain this:

```
pty "/usr/sbin/pptp <server_ip_address> --nolaunchpppd"
name <your_login_name>
remotename <identifier>
require-mppe-128
file /etc/ppp/options.pptp
ipparam <ipparam_id>
```

Replace the `server_ip_address` and the `your_login_name` with the appropriate values. The `identifier` will be used for supplying a password (see below). The `ipparam_id` is used by the scripts in `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/`. It is needed if you want to do something with the tunnel interface (adding routes, maybe -- see below).

You need to supply your password. The password is stored in a plaintext file (which sucks, be sure to chown the file to 0600). The file is `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets`, anbd it should contain a line like this:

```
your_login_name    identifier    <your_password>    *
```

The first two parameters is from the peer file.

If you want to do something when the PPTP tunnel starts and/or stops, you need to add scripts to the `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/` and the `/etc/ppp/ip-down.d/` directories. Every script in these directories will be run upon (de)activating a ppp tunnel. The following global variables exported for the scripts (there are others, but these are the most useful):

- `PPPD_PID`: The PID of the pppd process
- `PPP_IFACE`: The interface in question
- `PPP_IPPARAM`: The ipparam_id, which is given in the peer file
- `PPP_LOCAL`: The local IP address assigned to the ppp interface
- `PPP_REMOTE`: The remote IP address assigned to the ppp interface

After all this, you can use the

```
pon <peer file>
```

to start the PPTP tunnel, and the

```
poff <peer file>
```

to stop it.

Comment: pppd seems to be included in Ubuntu by default and is not found as a package to install

Comment: works great - perfect tutorial

Answer (score 2):

This is a good site: http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net

1. Usually, we can setup PPTP VPN connection using "pptpsetup" command

   ```
   pptpsetup --create Test_VPN --server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --domain MyDomain --username MyName --password mypassword --encrypt
   ```
2. Start the VPN connection

   ```
   pppd call Test_VPN
   ```
3. If something is wrong, here is the debug command

   ```
   pppd call Test_VPN logfd 2 nodetach debug dump
   ```

On ubuntu, I think the package you need is pptp-linux, you can install it by the command:

```
apt-get install pptp-linux
```